# Website not reachable after I removed and reinstalled web deployment tool

Tags: web-services, http

I have been having an issue with deploying to my website management service, after following a lot of information from various forums, I came to one that said by uninstalling and reinstalling the web deployment tool solved his problem, the problem is now that both of my websites are not reachable.

After running the following command in cmd...

netstat -aon | findstr 80

Its listening on the following..

TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4

But no where in the listing do i find the following TCP  0.0.0.0:80

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this particular issue with the following command...

netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0

:-)